# Model for a Repeated Measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, linear-model

How do I write a model for comparing a single dependent variable (BacterialDiversity) among three groups (CO, HF, HFS) over time?

```
 Treatment Time BacterialDiversity BacterialEvenness ViralDiversity   ViralEvenness
   CO    0           5.049012         0.7334988          3.798800     0.7532183
   CO    0           5.128714         0.7419217          3.867314     0.7513003
   CO    0           4.980878         0.7221065          3.741372     0.7284889
   HF    0           5.228662         0.7550837          4.005882     0.7799921
   HF    0           5.432559         0.7895721          3.727871     0.7266948
   HF    0           4.995693         0.7238313          3.641686     0.7175489
```

*Full datasheet found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17XzR41LkUE_2d2mnWs24H9iTx7MvYhWNocApmnUpvPk/edit?usp=sharing)